# Stream.CopyToAsync() with cancellation token not available in PCLs / WP8 when targeting Xamarin too?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, async-await

Am I blind or is

```
public virtual Task CopyToAsync(
    Stream destination,
    int bufferSize,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
)
```

really not available in PCLs? 
My profile is: .NET 4.5, Windows Store, WP8, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh158751%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) claims it is available for .NET 4.5 and Windows Store...it's on Android and on iOS but not in a PCL targeting these?

What's a good cancelable workaround for

```
await result.Content.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
```

Comment: It's available in PCL project with Windows Store, WP8 and .NET 4.5 checked. Any other configuration makes it unavailable (checking Silverlight or Phone in version < 8)

Comment: Adjusted my question. I'm also targeting Android and iOS.

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20903958/1768303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* available in the PCL, but it depends on the targets platforms you selected. I use it in a project that targets .NET 4.5, Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store apps. But if you select a target platform that doesn't have this overload (perhaps Silverlight or WP7), then it won't be available for the PCL.

In your case, I assume this method is not supported in Xamarin...

Comment: I have just reviewed the code. Should look close before posting here. I'm not dealing with a Stream but with an HttpContent object which happens to have a CopyToAsync(). I will accept your answer because the explanation is correct wrt profile selection.